# Jmeter - While converting CSV data to base64 with groovy getting below error

Tags: groovy, jmeter, read.csv

Code >

[image]

Error >

[image]

Help to solve this error!

Purpose is to pass

```
${encodedPayload}
```

to http post request. Currently getting ${encodedPayload} instead of base64 encoded data.

Comment: read the stacktrace. It tells you what is missing. for future reference, don't post pictures of code, post actual code that is sufficient to reproduce the issue

Comment: Try this vars.get("name") and vars.get("type") instead of ${name} and ${type}

Answer (score 0):

From the error it seems that your `${type}` string doesn't have any value.

If you're trying to use [String Interpolation](https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_string_interpolation) - make sure to define it beforehand:

```
def type = "some type"
//and then you can refer it anywhere as "${type}"
```

if you're trying to reference a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) - make sure that it exists and has an anticipated value using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debug-jmeter). Additionally you should rather use `vars` shorthand for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance, i.e. instead of:

```
${type}
```

use

```
vars.get("type")
```

In general you don't need any scripting, if you just need to send Base64-encoded JSON you could just go for [__base64Encode()](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#base64Encodesupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-2-0-font-sup) custom JMeter Function (can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/))